# AsyncTaskbackbutton

Tags: android, android-asynctask

am able to sucessfully get data from the server.if data is success then am navigating NextScreen.1. if backbutton pressed when getting data then AsyncTask Dialog disappear, but after sometime it navigates to Nextscreen activity. so if i press backbuttob asyn task has to cancel and it should not navigate to next activity.

```
    public class Screenone extends Activity {
    EditText user,pass;
    Button login;           
    InputStream is;
    String productResponse;
    EditText edit;   
    int responseCode;               

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
    setContentView(R.layout.mainlog);       

    user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user);
    pass =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);     
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);

   }    

    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

            if ((user.getText().length() > 0)
                    && (pass.getText().length() > 0) ) {                
                new Load().execute(Status);
            }
                    }
    });

   }


   private class Load extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginScreen.this);
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        Dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        Dialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... status) { 
                try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();                     

     HttpPost post = new HttpPost("---url---");                     
            responseCode =httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        }           


        catch (Exception e) {           
                            }                     
        return null;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String Result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(Result);      

            if (responseCode==200) {            
            Dialog.dismiss();           

            Intent intent =new Intent(Screenone.this, NextScreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);                          
                        }           

                            }               
            }


   public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();

     moveTaskToBack(true);

   }

   }
```

Comment: I think you have to finish() the started activity so that i will not retain the values...

Comment: call http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean) onback and your asynctask will not call onPostExecute()

Answer (score 0):

OK the problem is that you have no reference to your asynctask. Try creating a property in your Activity for the asynctask:

```
private Load myAsyncTask;
```

now in your onClick method:

```
myAsyncTask=new Load();

myAsyncTask.execute(Status);
```

and finally in your onBackPressed:

```
 public void onBackPressed() {
    super...
    if(myAsyncTask!=null)
         myAsyncTask.cancel(true);
 }
```

Comment: i changed as per your suggestion but still am getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to Cancel AsyncTask, dismiss ProgressDialog and also abort HttpPost before moving back from current Activity . try it as :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     if(Load!=null){
        if(!Load.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
           // first abort Httppost request 
           // post.abort();   
           httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

           // now dismiss ProgressDialog
            if (Dialog!=null&&Dialog.isShowing()) {
                 Dialog.dismiss();
             }
           // now cancel AsyncTask if running
            if(Load.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
              Load.cancel(true);
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: as per your suggestion i have done like this but still am getting the same issue..

Comment: @user2042881 : if u are getting any issue then update your question with latest code and full log when app crashing

Comment: public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed(); 
     LoginScreen.Load xx = new LoginScreen().new Load();          
     if(new Load()!=null){
         if(!(new Load().getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)){
              
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
          
             if (xx.Dialog!=null&&xx.Dialog.isShowing()) {
                  xx.Dialog.dismiss();
              }
           
             if(new Load().getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
              new Load().cancel(true);
              }
          }    
     
     }
   }

Comment: @user2042881 : what happening when u are running this code ? and edit all code and log in question instead of posting it in comment